# scrollable menu with Jquery

Tags: html, css

How can I make an scrollable menu with Jquery?

```css
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar { 
   display: none; 
                   }
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
     <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
       <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
         <a href="#about">About</a>
         
  ...
</div>
```

I have this horizontal scrollable menu, in css

**PROBLEM**

I dont want it to show the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: 'overflow: hidden;' shouldn't actually stop content from being moved around, it just hides overflow

Answer (score 1):

For the `Chrome` Browser you can use

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

for your CSS.

And for more maybe this will work for you. [Pure CSS Horizontal Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/)

Sorry for the misunderstanding, here is a JS way, [HIDE VERTICAL & HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR OF A DIV](https://davidsekar.com/jquery/hide-vertical-horizontal-scrollbar-of-a-div)

Comment: this link  ...Pure Css Horizontal...doesnt work on mobile....just mouse

Comment: what about other browsers? If I add this css hack, it doesnt work  for mouse.